# Demystifying LOWORD macro pseudocode into valid C

Tags: c, windows, pseudocode, decompiling, ida

From IDA decompilation of a subroutine into C pseudocode, I encountered this line of code:

`LOWORD(v9) = *(BYTE *)v6);`

Where `v9, v6` are 32-bit integers.

`LOWORD` is a macro defined in `windef.h` as follows:

`#define LOWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))`

Obviously it's a macro, so I can't assign things to it. I am interested an implementation which would be valid C, but I am unsure of the decompiler's intent here. From my guess, the intent is to dereference the `LOWORD` of `v9`, and assign the byte value pointed by `v6`, but I would like to make sure.

In the event that it may be necessary, here is the context of the pseudocode. All types are 32-bit integers:

```
if (*(BYTE *)v6) {
    LOWORD(v9) = *(BYTE *)v6);
    do {
        v7 = v7 & 0xFFFF0000 | (unsigned __int16)(v7 + v9);
        v9 = *++v8;
        if (*v8) {
            v7 = (unsigned __int16)v7 | ((*v8++ + (v7 >> 16)) << 16);
            v9 = *v8;
        }
    } while (v9);
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it just writes to the low word of `v9`, e.g. `*(WORD *)v9 = *(BYTE *)v6` assuming little-endian.  Or if you like, `v9 = (v9 & 0xffff0000) | *(BYTE *)v6`, much like what appears two lines down.  This might be an example where the disassembly is more informative than the decompiler output.

Comment: I mean `*(WORD *)&v9` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `windef.h` macro you show is *not* the one being used by IDA, since as you noticed you cannot use the result of such a macro as an lvalue.

> From my guess, the intent is to dereference the `LOWORD` of `v9`, and assign the byte value pointed by `v6`

Not quite. The intent is to replace the low word (that is the lower 2 bytes) of the variable `v9` (which is an `int`) with the right hand side.

So in IDA, this:

```c
LOWORD(a) = b;
```

Can be seen as this:

```c
a = (a & 0xffff0000) | b;
```

The way to write such a macro in C would be something like:

```c
#define LOWORD(x) (*((uint16_t*)&(x)))
```

Which is a possibly more convoluted, yet more versatile way of doing the same thing, and can be used both as an lvalue and an rvalue.